# How do I make sure I'm not appearing on other people's email as "Do you know <me>?"

Tags: gmail, google-plus

From time to time Google decides to tell me that I might know some people by their G+ profile from whom I only ever contact via email. (I don't, and don't want to, know or have to do anything with their G+ account)

Case in point: I have this person `xyz@gmail.com` with whom I exchanged a few emails about 1-3 years ago. Now he's showing up in my email.

[image: the email in my inbox]

Similarly, I'm sure he must be getting same email about me.

I repeat, I don't want these people whom I only contact via gmail to find my G+ profile.

What do I do to make that sure?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Google+ settings:
https://www.google.com/settings/plus

Uncheck these:

[image]

Remove unnecessary email contacts from Gmail, check also the "Other contacts":
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14001?hl=en&ref_topic=1284985

I hope this helps!

Comment: Nice to have a TC on Web Applications!!

Comment: Hi Jan! :-)  We try to help where we can...